# How to assign multiple TAX classes for customer group?

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, customer-group, multiple

Hi I need to assign multiple TAX classes for different customer group.

For example:

I have three customer group: `group1`, `group2`, `group3`

For `group1` ***2%*** tax will be applicable.

But for `group2` ***2%*** and ***5%*** both will be applicable.

And for for `group3` ***no TAX*** will be applicable.

Can anyone please suggest me how I can solve this problem?

Any kind of support

Comment: how will you distinguish between the case when you have to apply 2% and when you have to apply 5% for the same group?

Comment: Hi Marius, I don't need to distinguish them, 2% and 5% both will be applicable at once for group2

Comment: That does not make much sense. Maybe you should give an example. List 2-3 products with their prices and explain what their price and tax should be when they are added to the cart for each customer group.

Comment: @Marius I have already applied 2% and 5% TAX at a time. But I am facing difficulties while I am going to get same product for different group.

Comment: @Marius Can you please just suggest me how I can apply different tax class for different group?